# Blogger Custom Subdomain does not work with Cloudflare DNS

Tags: web-hosting, blogger, cloudflare

I have set up Cloudflare to redirect www.hanxue.co and the naked domain hanxue.co to my blog http://hanxue.blogspot.com - works without any problem.

When I change the subdomain to blog.hanxue.co, the redirect does not work. Here is my Cloudflare DNS settings:

[image: Cloudflare DNS settings for hanxue.co]

This is the error I got when I visit the domain:

[image: Blogger redirect error]

Note that changing the CNAME entry of `blog` to `www` and updating DNS settings at Blogger to www, works perfectly fine.

Comment: That's not an error... it's simply informing the user that the website has moved. It's perfectly normal, and why do you have 4 A records pointing to 4 different IP addresses?

Comment: It is an error. When I go to http://blog.hanxue.co, I see that message. Clicking will simply redirect me to the same page. A PTR is required for custom domain as per https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/1233387?hl=en&ref_topic=6321959

Comment: You need to tell Google of the sub domain `BLOG` you can't use `anything-you-want.example.com` without informing Google. This is because at their servers they add the subdomain to their virtual host configuration. So please edit your question and include the screenshot of you adding the cname 'BLOG' during the setup of your custom domain.

Comment: fyi, 4 A records pointing to 4 different IP addresses   is part of the correct setup for pointing a a blog made with Blogger to a custom domain.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you have  redirected www.hanxue.co and the naked domain hanxue.co to your blog http://hanxue.blogspot.com

But I wonder if you really want to redirect your blog http://hanxue.blogspot.com   to    your custom domain www.hanxue.co  or perhaps a subdomain of it like    www.blog.hanxue.co

If that is the case, then you need to start in Blogger:   Use the Settings > Basic > Publishing item to choose the re-direction, and then use the information from this screen in Cloudflare to set up you CNAME record(s).